# C++ destructor fail on custom buffer - How does compiler really generate destructors' code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, destructor

I'm using visual studio 2015 building some **single-thread** C++ project.

I have a very crude pool that the rest of project acquire memory and return back to it. It runs with no problem before `return 0;` in main. After that, I know there's some compiler generated code for exiting, in which it called some *scalar deleting destructor* of my own class (`class foo` below).

Here's some assembly code of the scalar deleting destructor (I hide the name of those class and namespace by `aaaaa` and `foo`):

```
000000013FC30FC0  mov         dword ptr [rsp+10h],edx  
000000013FC30FC4  mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx  
000000013FC30FC9  push        rbp  
000000013FC30FCA  push        rdi  
000000013FC30FCB  sub         rsp,0E8h  
000000013FC30FD2  lea         rbp,[rsp+20h]  
000000013FC30FD7  mov         rdi,rsp  
000000013FC30FDA  mov         ecx,3Ah  
000000013FC30FDF  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
000000013FC30FE4  rep stos    dword ptr [rdi]  
000000013FC30FE6  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+108h]  
000000013FC30FEE  mov         rcx,qword ptr [this]  
000000013FC30FF5  call        aaaaa::foo::~foo (013FC2381Bh)  
000000013FC30FFA  mov         eax,dword ptr [rbp+0E8h]  
000000013FC31000  and         eax,1  
000000013FC31003  test        eax,eax  
000000013FC31005  je          aaaaa::foo::`scalar deleting destructor'+58h (013FC31018h)  
000000013FC31007  mov         edx,30h  
000000013FC3100C  mov         rcx,qword ptr [this]  
000000013FC31013  call        operator delete (013FC2661Ah)  
000000013FC31018  mov         rax,qword ptr [this]  
000000013FC3101F  lea         rsp,[rbp+0C8h]  
000000013FC31026  pop         rdi  
000000013FC31027  pop         rbp  
000000013FC31028  ret
```

In debugging session I finally find out where the problem arose. In the normal running phase (i.e. in the major part of main function), `000000013FC30FFA  mov  eax,dword ptr [rbp+0E8h]` would set `eax` to 0, and thus bypass those several lines of code after `je`, and most crucially bypass the call to `operator delete`.

But on the last hit of those lines, `eax` was set to 1 after the `mov`, and then execute the call to `operator delete` and at exactly that line it **triggered a break point at `operator delete`**.

So my questions are:

1. Is scalar deleting destructor a unique concept in Visual Studio, that is, it's not seen in any other compilers? (This is perfectly answered in immibis' answer, and it's yes)
2. In what case the above code would set `eax` to 1 after call to my custom destructor? Why is the compiler doing this, that is, what's the object `operator delete` originally to delete?
3. Is the execution of `operator delete` a double deletion?
4. Must I trace back to the change on `rbp+0E8h` to see how the error occurs? (Any other way to do?)

---

**EDIT** about the class:
The `foo` class (which is my own class mentioned above) have all (raw) pointer members, which itself have all ownership of those pointers, i.e. responsible for deleting them. And the `buffer_t` below is the underlying pool or buffer which is basically a large region of raw memory partitioned providing interface of allocate and deallocate for single (i.e. not array or alike) object.

Minimal reproduce of the classes:

```
template <typename T>
struct other_t{
    // members, but none of them are pointer member
    other_t(){}// ctor with argument in reality
    static buffer_t buffer;
};

struct foo{
    other_t<some_T>* ptr;
    foo(const foo&)=delete;
    foo& operator=(const foo&)=delete;
    //~foo{ delete ptr; } //originally
    ~foo{ other_t<some_T>::buffer.deallocate(ptr); }; // actually
};
```

---

*PS: I'm not familiar with assembly language and if the above is not enough for solving the problem, please comment below, thanks.*

Comment: Is this real compiler output?  `mov  rcx,qword ptr [rsp+108h]` followed by `mov   rcx,qword ptr [this]` seems unlikely.  (The 2nd instruction overwrites the only result of the first).

Comment: @PeterCordes I copied directly from the `Disassembly` window from Visual Studio, and I compiled in debug mode.

Comment: Ok, debug mode (un-optimized) explains braindead asm with redundant instructions.  It's harder to read than optimized asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes, Is that? But it seems the compiler would directly jump over this range of code in optimized code, or I just can't locate them:-/

Comment: @YiFei *in which it called some scalar deleting destructor of my own class* -- We need to see this "own class".  Those "scalar deleting destructor" errors can occur for a variety of reasons.  An invalid instance, a class that does not have correct copy semantics, etc.  Also, why are you delving into assembly code?  Why not look at your C++ source for the errors?

Comment: @YiFei *It runs with no problem before return 0;* -- Which means it was running with a problem you didn't notice.  You just identified where the program finally breaks down, not where the start of the issue occurs.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Yep, quite possibly I haven't noticed it (also have no clue about it). And I added some info about the classes. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Ugh, I got to admit I was kinda lazy at that time, but I don't copy them in my code and I've added such two lines and it compiled.

Comment: @YiFei Is this a mutlithreaded program?  What is `buffer_t`?

Comment: @oldrinb -- That is how you turn off copying using C++11.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, buffer_t is that crude pool mentioned above (see my edited question), do you need any more information?

Comment: @YiFei -- You didn't state whether the program is multithreaded or not.

Answer (score 1):

> Is scalar deleting destructor a unique concept in Visual Studio, that is, it's not seen in any other compilers?

Yes.

> In what case the above code would set eax to 1 after call to my custom destructor?

In the case where the low bit of the 4-byte value at `rbp + 0x0E8` is 1.

What is your actual problem?

Comment: Thanks for fast response, so would that finally do a double deletion? And about my actual problem, it's a crash anyway, and I'm gonna solve it...

Comment: @YiFei "Would that finally do a double deletion?" - who knows? I don't. Especially without seeing the source code.